# Numbers in CSV file generated by Excel

Tags: excel, csv, vsto

Unfortunately, Excel is not very programmer-friendly when it generates CSV files, as it stores numbers as they appear on the screen. How numbers look like in the CSV therefore depends on the regional settings and the taste of the user.

As a result, I may end up with numbers looking like

```
2 123
3'322
1,233.44
2123,45
```

etc.

And now I must process such CSV files in my program.

Apart from telling the users how to build their CSV files -- is there any smart or canonical solution how to deal with this problem? Switching to another data format would be an option as well -- but which one? It must be natively supported by Excel, and it should be easy to handle (so I would like to avoid xlsx).

Comment: What is wrong with xlsx? It is complicated, but there are solutions for it like EPPLUS, which can read / write xlsx and even supports LINQ.
For the CSV: Excel store no metadata about this, so it would be difficult to guess the country

Comment: I would suggest using some other file format than CSV. I know this isn't really an answer, but of course a CSV file is going to give you trouble when confronted with a number like 1,233.44 (!). Can your users send you workbooks? Or even tab-delimited text files would be better.

Comment: Don't I have the same problem if I let Excel generate tab-delimited text files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem with a client, I have written them an export to csv macro that explicitly tells excel the formatting of each column, here is an example of the code

```
Public Sub Export_To_CSV()
'Give excel the sheet with data to be exported to CSV

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

'Declare your string array to be filled - currently set to 5 columns

Dim csvread(1 To 5) As String
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

Dim ObjFso
Dim StrFileName
Dim ObjFile

'Name the export csv - This will generate it in the folder you have the excel you are working with in and then names it CSVexport-Day-Month.csv

StrFileName = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\CSVExport-" & Day(Date) & "-" & Month(Date) & ".csv"
Set ObjFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Creating a file for writing data
Set ObjFile = ObjFso.CreateTextFile(StrFileName)

'takes the headers from row 1 - set by i if different

csvread(1) = Range("A" & i).Value
csvread(2) = Range("B" & i).Value
csvread(3) = Range("C" & i).Value
csvread(4) = Range("D" & i).Value
csvread(5) = Range("E" & i).Value

'Writes the Headers

ObjFile.WriteLine (csvread(1) & "," & csvread(2) & "," & csvread(3) & "," & csvread(4) & "," & csvread(5))

i = i + 1

'Do until loop can be altered to meet your parameters

Do Until Range("A" & i).Value = 0 Or i = 1000

'format your data however you require

csvread(15) = Format(Range("A" & i).Value, "###0.00")
csvread(15) = Format(Range("B" & i).Value, "###0.00")
csvread(15) = Format(Range("C" & i).Value, "###0.00")
csvread(15) = Format(Range("D" & i).Value, "###0.00")
csvread(15) = Format(Range("E" & i).Value, "###0.00")

'write the line to the file

ObjFile.WriteLine (csvread(1) & "," & csvread(2) & "," & csvread(3) & "," & csvread(4) & "," & csvread(5))
i = i + 1
Loop

ObjFile.Close

p = MsgBox("Exported", vbOKOnly)


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Indeed, I have now built an export procedure myself.

Answer (score 0):

Up to now, I haven't found any better solution other than exporting the file myself (`CsvWriter` is a custom class, but straightforward -- `CsvWriter.WriteItems` takes an enumerable of strings, quotes them if necessary, and builds a line in the csv file out of them):

```
public static class CsvExporter {

    public static void ExportWorksheet (
        CsvWriter csvWriter,
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet,
        Action<int,int> reportProgressCallback = null
    ) {
        foreach (var row in WorksheetToStrings (worksheet, reportProgressCallback))
            csvWriter.WriteItems (row);
    }



    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> WorksheetToStrings (
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet, Action<int,int> reportProgressCallback = null
    ) {
        var usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
        return RangeToStrings (usedRange, reportProgressCallback);
    }



    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> RangeToStrings (
        Excel.Range range,
        Action<int,int> reportProgressCallback = null
    ) {
        if (reportProgressCallback == null)
            reportProgressCallback = (line, total) => { };

        int rowsTotal = range.Rows.Count;
        int currentRow = 0;
        foreach (var row in range.Rows) {
            ++currentRow;
            reportProgressCallback (currentRow, rowsTotal);
            var rowValues = (row as Excel.Range).Value2 as object;
            foreach (
                var convertedRow in
                convertToEnumerableOfEnumerablesOfStrings (rowValues)
            )
                yield return convertedRow;

        }
    }



    private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>
    convertToEnumerableOfEnumerablesOfStrings (
        object values
    ) {
        return  convertToEnumerableOfEnumerablesOfObjects (values)
                    .Select (
                        r => r.Select (
                            c => convertSingleValueToString (c)
                        )
                    );
    }

    private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>>
    convertToEnumerableOfEnumerablesOfObjects (
        object values
    ) {
        var ary = values as object [,];
        if (ary != null)
            return convertTwoDimAryToEnumerableOfEnumerablesOfObjects (ary);

        var obj = values as object;
        if (obj != null)
            return Enumerable.Repeat<IEnumerable<object>> (
                Enumerable.Repeat<object> (obj, 1), 1
            );

        return Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<object>> ();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>>
    convertTwoDimAryToEnumerableOfEnumerablesOfObjects (
        object [,] ary
    ) {
        var firstUpperBound = ary.GetUpperBound (0);
        var secondUpperBound = ary.GetUpperBound (1);
        return Enumerable.Range (1, firstUpperBound).Select (
            i => Enumerable.Range (1, secondUpperBound).Select (j => ary [i, j])
        );
    }

    private static string convertSingleValueToString (object value) {
        if ( value == null ) {
            return string.Empty;
        } else if (value is string) {
            return value as string;
        } else if (value is long) {
            return ((long) value).ToString (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        } else if (value is double) {
            return ( (double) value ).ToString (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        } else if (value is bool) {
            return (bool) value ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";
        } else {
            return value.ToString ();
        }
    }


}
```